# How to add jquery mobile to an EXISTING Worklight 6.2 project

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

Is there any working way to add jquery mobile widgets to an aleady existing project (not creating another one from scratch)?
Since I have worked already a lot at this project I really can't start from scratch again.
`Worklight version is 6.2`
This project is imported and originally it didn't have JQuery libraries. I already know how to add them when CREATING a new project, the question is:
is it possible to add jquery in an existing project?
Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new application with jQuery Mobile, look at the template and do the same in your existing project...?

1. Place whereever you want the jQuery Mobile .css and .js files - for example in the common\css and common\js folders
2. Reference these files in index.html in the HEAD like you would any other .css and .js files (again, take a look at a project that already has jQuery Mobile added to it via the wizard)
3. in index.html, change the body content accordingly, to just how it looks like in an application that jQuery Mobile was added to it...